# scss mixin linear-gradient, two variables made easy?

Tags: sass

I have a list of elements that need some gradient colors. But how can I make a simple mixin that simplifies the whole thing?

For example, in my css I'd like to be able to write:

```
button { @include linear(blue); }
```

and then scss would use my mixin and include my colors in my variables

```
$redTop: #F67777;
$redBottom: #E65050;

$blueTop: #77CFF6;
$blueBottom: #50B9E6;

@mixin linear($color) {
  background-image: linear-gradient($colorTop, $colorBottom);
}
```

Comment: Your linear mixin should work fine, but all you needed to do was define colorTop and colorBottom. Name one mixin red and the other mixin blue and reference those colors. Then just include whichever mixin you need in your SASS. You can make a map out of them, but thats just extra code

Comment: I already have that solution you mentioned, but I wanted to make it easier by just defining a single color

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'd want to split the colours into a map.

```
$red: (
  "top": #f00,
  "bottom": #c00
);

@mixin linear($color) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(map-get($color, "top"), map-get($color, "bottom"));
}

.red-bg {
  @include linear($red);
}
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work. It won't compile it in Visual Studio Code. I just copy-pasted your solution into my variables.scss file to see how it would work. What am I missing?